# the maximum value of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{101} 1729x_1x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_{101}$ are positive real number satisfying the following equation

$$x_1^2 +x^2_2+...+x_{101}^2=1$$

Find the maximum value of  $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{101} 1729x_1x_n$

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: You already asked the question before. What happened to that one?

Comment: I asked the minimum in last question but actually the problem is finding maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two vectors in $\Bbb R^{100}$: $x=(x_1,\dots,x_1)$ with $\|x\|=|x_1|\sqrt{100}$ and $y=(x_2,\dots,x_{101})$ with $\|y\|=\sqrt{x_2^2+\dots+x_{101}^2}=\sqrt{1-x_1^2}$. By Schwarz Inequality we have $$\left|\sum_{i=2}^{102}1729x_1x_i\right|=1729|\langle x,y\rangle|\le 1729\|x\|\cdot\|y\|=1729\sqrt{100}|x_1|\cdot\sqrt{1-x_1^2}.$$ Now find the maximum to this function of one variable. This task is rather standard, so I finish my solution here. In the final step take into account that the equality in Schwarz inequality is attained for linearly dependent vectors. Hence it is really enough to maximize this function on the right.

Comment: @GNUSupporter, thank you very much. :-)